# react native external keyboard handler

Tags: keyboard, react-native

how I can handle external keyboard events like pressing arrow keys (without a TextInput) ?
I'm trying to accomplish this because I need to receive some information from a external device that acts just like a keyboard

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

We use [react-native-keyevent](https://github.com/kevinejohn/react-native-keyevent) to handle events from bluetooth keyboard. You can check if it suits your needs.